# ASP.NET 4.5 Membership and oAuth Tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.5

Does anyone know how i can get the oAuth part on the ASP.NET membership moved to my MS SQL DB, rather than use localdb which its seems to be doing by default?

I have my users all set up in my SQL db, however the UsersOpenAuthAccounts and UsersOpenAuthData are stored in a localdb.

I am using ASP.NET 4.5, not the MVC framework... just incase that helps.

Update: When i change my connection string to "DefaultConnection" the oAuth" tables are then created in my DB. I suppose this will do. But how do i change the deafult connection to something different?

Alan

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenAuth.ConnectionString to specify the name of the connection string to use. I do this in the RegisterOpenAuth method AuthConfig.cs file in the app_start folder.

Comment: do you have an example?