# Change the database in which ASP.NET Identity stores user data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We have created a new ASP.NET 4.5.1 project as follows:

- Visual Studio 2013
- New Project
- Visual C#
- Web
- ASP.NET Web Application
- Web API
- Change Authentication
- Individual User Accounts
- Okay > Okay

In the solution explorer > App_Start > Startup.Auth.cs file there is the following code which configures ASP.NET Indentity. How do we change the database in which the UserManager stores user data?

```
static Startup()
{
    PublicClientId = "self";

    UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };
}
```

Comment: Doesn't UserStore have multiple constructors...

Comment: And doesn't one take a DbContext...

Comment: Yup. It does that too.

Comment: So http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx or I believe the default constructor of UserStore will make it itself, using "DefaultConnection" for the connection string name. So you can edit that in web.config.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Additionally to what @ta.speot.is and @Shaun mentioned: You can also pass the name of the connection string (stored in the web.config) in your context to the [base constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457110%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) of the IdentityDbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
{
  public MyDbContext()
    : base("TheNameOfTheConnectionString")
  {
  }
}
```

This [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx) contains an extensive example.

Another way would be to use the name of the connection string as a parameter of your context constructor and pass it to the base constructor.

Comment: Aha. So you make MyDbContext inherit the IdentityDbContext. What is the different between doing that and inheriting the normal DbContext?

Comment: **IdentityDbContext** is the context provided by ASP.NET Identity. It inherits from **DbContext** and adds two DbSets for the user and role management. For some more information have a look a [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902756/asp-net-identity-dbcontext-confusion).

Comment: It doesn't work, could you please take a look at my question. thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393195/userstore-with-my-own-database

Answer (score 8):

Pass your own `DbContext` to the `UserStore` constructor or change the Web.config connection string named `DefaultConnection`. Either way the comments by @ta.speot.is are correct.

**Correct**

```
// do this - it's the factory pattern
UserManagerFactory 
= () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new MyDbContext()));
```

**Incorrect**

```
// do NOT do this - use the preceding code. 
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new MyDbContext());                       
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
UserManagerFactory = () => userManager;
```

**Details**

The `UserStore` class exposes a *very basic* user management api. In code, we configure it to store user data as type `IdentityUser` in the `MyDbContext` data store.

The `UserManager` class exposes a higher level user management api that automatically saves changes to the `UserStore`. In code, we configure it to use the `UserStore` that we just created.

The `UserManagerFactory` should implement the factory pattern in order to get one instance of `UserManager` per request for the application. Otherwise you will get the following exception:

> The context cannot be used while the model is
>   being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used
>   inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is
>   accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members
>   of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

That's all.