# ASP .NET Web API 2 Individual Accounts with MSSQL Not LocalDB

Tags: asp.net-web-api, code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, database-first

I'm using **Web API 2** for mobile clients. Web API uses "**Individual Accounts**" for authenticate in my project. I created database with MSSQL on remote server and my API 's structe likes "**Wep API 2 + MSSQL**" (*Database First*). But "**Individual Accounts**" uses "*Code First*" so uses local db. I don't want this. I want to use database on remote MSSQL with "**Web API 2**". How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

change the following line in IdentityModel.cs

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
```

to

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("YourConnectionStringsName")
```

Comment: Additionally to the post above you should have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343846/change-the-database-in-which-asp-net-identity-stores-user-data/21344228#21344228). You only have to do two things: Add the connection string of your remote DB to your web.config and change the call to the base class in the constructor of your context (like shown above).