# EF CodeFirst- Merging two DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I have two `DbContext`, one for Asp.net Identity and other one is for the rest of my domain. Now according to this design I have many problems to manage Initializing database. As you may know I would like to seed those tables belong to each `DbContext` which has its own issues. I want to know is this good idea to merge those `DbContext` instead of having one for each one?

Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would do just a single DBContext for both Identity entities and other. This way you can easily build relationships between you user/roles entities and the rest of your domain.

Are you using Identity 2.0? Take a look at this question: [ASP.NET Identity DbContext confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902756/asp-net-identity-dbcontext-confusion)