# DbContext class in Asp.net MVC 5 with Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

You need to have a context class that derives from DbContext when you're using Entity Framework.

Asp.net Identity uses EF and the default template creates the below class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

This class does not derive **directly** from DbContext. For my own data (my classes that I want to persist to the db) should I create my own db context class?

If I want to do an operation that will update both the identity user and one of my own classes, I need to use both contexts. So this does not feel very natural.

Should I keep using the ApplicationDbContext class as context for my own classes as well? Would that work?

What is the best method to use EF for my own classes while using identity?

Comment: Read up the inheritance chain.... IdentityDbContext is a derivative of DbContext.

Comment: I'd use separate contexts in my apps but then I'd also be using Repository pattern so at some level it really doesn't matter. Separate contexts can be valuable if you deploy your membership system to a different server from domain db as per the SOP of many large companies.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that IdentityDbContext does not derive from DbContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single Context class inheriting from IdentityDbContext. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19904081/242) for more info.

You need to add DbSets for all your classes into the ApplicationDbContext.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", false)
    {
    }

    //Public DBSets
    public DbSet<LeaveApplication> LeaveApplications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LeaveStatus> LeaveStatus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```