# .NET 7.0 Cannot insert record into database with DBContext. Getting error such as Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Invalid column name 'RoleId'

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I am writing a new web application using .NET 7.0. I had issues automating the process of creating models based on my existing database. The packages failed to install or run correctly.

As a result I built the context and models manually. This includes the models for my user & user role tables that support Identity.

I am running into an issue using the `DbContext`'s `Add()` and `SaveChanges()` methods to add new records to any entity. Direct SQL script executions work fine, but the two methods I mention are always failing; even with the simplest tables.

I have a table named `Role_Assignment`. It has only 2 columns, and both make up a compound primary key.

When trying to insert a record using `Add()`, I am getting strange behavior. Firstly, the system tells me it cannot find a field that does not exist in the table. i.e. "Invalid column name `RoleID`".

After many attempts, I changed my model to use a `RoleID` field and mapped it to the correct DB column using an attribute (`[Column("Role_ID")]`).

After making the change, cleaning and recompiling the solution. The error message changed to say "Invalid column name 'RoleId1'". As much as I tried to change my model to conform to the invisible columns that the frame work is trying to mirror, it would not accept my changes. I'm guessing that if I created a column RoleId1, then the error would increment to the next number RoleID2.

It's not clear why .NET is exhibiting this behavior, and this has been bothering me for days. I could do a work-around of writing raw SQL script, but that is time consuming in a .NET environment.

If someone can point out what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate it.

Just a reminder that these classes were manually created.

Here is what I did:

In `Startup.cs` - `ConfigureServicesMethod`:

```
services.AddDbContext<IARTFDbContext, ARTFDbContext>(options =>
```

options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(_coreParams.connectionString)));

```
services.AddIdentity<SiteUser, Role>(options =>
                 {
                     options.Password.RequireDigit = _coreParams.RequireDigit;
                     options.Password.RequireLowercase = _coreParams.RequireLowercase;
                     options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = _coreParams.RequireNonAlphanumeric;
                     options.Password.RequireUppercase = _coreParams.RequireUppercase;
                     options.Password.RequiredLength = _coreParams.MinPWLength;
                     options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = (_coreParams.RequiredUniqueChars == false) ? 0 : 1;
                     options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_coreParams.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan);
                     options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = _coreParams.MaxFailedAccessAttempts;
                     options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = _coreParams.AllowedForNewUsers;
                     options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = _coreParams.AllowedUserNameCharacters;
                     options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = _coreParams.RequireUniqueEmail;
                 }//Identity options
              ).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ARTFDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Entity definition `Role_Assigment.cs`:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; //i.e. [Key]
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;

namespace ARTFY.com.Data
{
    [Table("Role_Assignment", Schema="ARTF")]
    public class Role_Assignment
    {
        [Key, Column("role_Id", Order = 0)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column("siteUserID",Order = 1)]
        public int siteUserID { get; set; }

    } // End Class Role_Assignment
}
```

In custom `DbContext`:

```
public partial class ARTFDbContext : IdentityDbContext<SiteUser>, IARTFDbContext 
{
    //=== Tables or entities ===
    public DbSet<dbSiteUser> SiteUser { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Role { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Email_Confirmation_Code> Email_Confirmation_Code { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Password_reset_code> Password_reset_code { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role_Assignment> Role_Assignment { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role_Assignment>()
                            .HasKey(ra => new { ra.RoleId, ra.siteUserID }); //Already done in the entity definition; so not needed again here.
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        _coreParameters = new CoreParameters();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_coreParameters.connectionString);
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    public bool AddRoleAssigment(ARTFY.com.Data.Role_Assignment userRoleAssignment)
    {
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            string sql = @"SELECT * 
                           FROM ARTF.Role_Assignment ur " +
                         @"WHERE role_id =  " + userRoleAssignment.RoleId +
                         @" AND siteUserID = " + userRoleAssignment.siteUserID + ";";

            var results = this.ExecuteRawSqlQuery(sql);

            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                result = false;
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Add(userRoleAssignment);
                int numberOfChangesMade = this.SaveChanges(true);  //<<<=== Fails right here

                if (numberOfChangesMade > 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ts.save($"{ex.Message} {ex.StackTrace}", "ARTFDbContext - AddRoleAssignment");
            return false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

SQL Server table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTF.Role_Assignment       
( 
   role_id  int IDENTITY (1,1),
   siteuserid nVarchar(75) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (role_ID, username),
   FOREIGN KEY (siteuserid) REFERENCES ARTF.SiteUser(siteuserid),
   FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES ARTF.Role (role_id)  
);
```

Errors I find inside the `DbContext` tree:

> An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.Source: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

> System.Linq.IQueryable.ElementType = '((System.Linq.IQueryable)this.RoleAssignment).ElementType' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Invalid column name 'RoleId'

> IsCollectible = Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsCollectible cannot be called in this context.

Stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__107_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at ARTFY.com.Data.ARTFDbContext.AddRoleAssigment(Role_Assignment userRoleAssignment) in C:\Users\DEV\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\ARTFY.com\ARTFY.com\Data\ARTFDbContext.cs:line 605
```

1. I double checked the database table to make sure fields are correct.
2. I double checked the entity definition/class and changed the field to match the error.
3. Tried to see if there is an existing `RoleAssignment` class that I could extend
4. Used the fully qualified name of my `RoleAssignment` class in case there was a conflict
5. Checked `Startup.cs` configure services, checked the `DbContext`, cleaned the solution, and lastly I changed the Provider to see if it was a provider issue i.e. tried both `System.Data.SqlClient` and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`
6. Finally just minutes before submitting this question I changed the field name in the database and in the entity/class to `userRoleID`, and I am still getting the error "Invalid column name 'RoleId'"

Comment: It might be enough to simply let your DBContext inherit from IdentityDbContext - that will add all your identity relations without you having to re-invent the wheel.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35722688/1467914

Comment: change your `modelBuilder.Entity<Role_Assignment>() .HasKey(ra => new { ra.RoleId, ra.siteUserID });`  to `modelBuilder.Entity<Role_Assignment>().HasKey(ra => new { ra.role_Id , ra.siteUserID });`

Comment: Try adding `modelBuilder.Entity<Role_Assignment>().Property(x => x.RoleId).HasColumnName("role_id")` - curious to see if defining this way rather than using the attribute works. I suspect this because the error specifies "RoleId" - this is your property name so I don't think its being mapped properly.

Comment: Sounds like you have a badly configured navigation property. Since you haven't explicitly mapped one, EF has decided to configure a new foreign key column as a shadow property. You should look for all properties of type `Role_Assignment` in your model, and how the navigations have been configured. And if you can't see how the navigation has been configured, then EF is probably defining a new navigation and foreign key which you didn't allow for.

Comment: @topsail my DbContext inherits from IdentityDbContext. Could that be a a reason?

Comment: If you are not adding properties to `Role_Assignment` you don't need to (re)define it at all. EF will create and manage the join table for you under the hood.

Comment: @MateusZampol I created these tables before deciding to use Entity framework. I create tables, classes and databases manually. Once I decided I want to leverage EF and some middleware capabilities, I decided to merge the Entity Framework into the design.

Comment: @NCR Fair enough. You should be able to configure the many-to-many relation and map it to your table without the need for a `DbSet<Role_Assignment>`

Answer (score 0):

I am back with an update in case anyone experiencing this confusing error. I decided to do some housekeeping to figure out why the "dotnet ef migrations add Initial" did not work to begin with. This is what led me to building out the models manually.

One of the recommendations I received was to **clear out the nuget packages folder** under my user profile (Windows: %USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages
Linux/Mac: ~/.nuget/packages).

1. I Created a back up of Packages folder.
2. Compiled the solution; then saw new errors due to missing packages.
3. I restored the Packages folder.
4. Then compiled again with no errors.
5. Next fixed all warnings (yellow) in the solution; they were warnings related to unrelated classes.
6. I do not believe this step made a difference, but I did use a tool in VS Tools > SQL Server > Schema Comparison but it yielded nothing, as there were no options available for Project Schemas, and there was no Data-Tier application file. I do not believe this step was helpful.
7. After recompiling and running I am no longer getting the error message that I opened this ticket about. I believe these steps forced the clearance of a cache. My issue is resolved, and hopefully this helps out someone else.