# Best practices for integrating ASP.NET Identity - do they exist?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity with a new website and there don't seem to be many (any?) examples of how to do this in a decoupled manner. I do not want my domain model's `DomainUser` class to have to inherit from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.User`, so I've created a class that looks like this:

```
public class IdentityUser : User
{
    public virtual DomainUser DomainUser { get; private set; }
}
```

I've moved the `DbSet`s required by ASP.NET Identity into the same derived `DbContext` class as my domain models [as illustrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308959/set-oauth-connectionstring-property-in-net-4-5-1/19913398#19913398). I've linked the `IdentityUser` unidirectionally to the `DomainUser` via Fluent API like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasRequired(iu => iu.DomainUser).WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

This allows me to mostly separate the concerns of authorization and authentication from the behaviors defined in the `DomainUser` class. This is better than combining them into one class, but it still feels ugly. I still have references to the required ASP.NET Identity assemblies in my Domain project. I could create yet another project that held only my IdentityUser class and a reference to my Domain assembly to allow for the navigation property, but that starts to feel convoluted.

I feel like there should be a better, cleaner, more modular way to link Identity up to the domain without it resulting in tight coupling.

Has anyone come up with a better way of handling this? I'm hoping to garner the attention of those involved in the ASP.NET Identity project ([Hao Kung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1459890/hao-kung) et al) to provide direction here.

Comment: Identity Framework is still work of initial stage of new approach solving the issue of Authentication and Authorization with broader coverage to different functional cases. And its released on 17th Nov, 2013. And if you followup nightly build, you will see more dynamic changing coming up in near future as V1.1. So, in my opinion, any best practice created now, may not be viable for future.

Comment: Moreover, Identity Framework need not be tightly coupled, you can use IoC to work. But still in that case, you need to refer to the Core assembly as all contracts are defined in there.

Comment: 1.0 was released on October 17th, not November 17th, and on that date it became a general release package (prior to that it was in the release candidate stage). In other words, despite the fact that nightlies are available, v1.0 should be a fairly shored up product. While IoC us useful at the presentation level, it doesn't do much to break the coupling between the auth user model and the domain user model. Not to mention that we're left with a db table with just two fields dangling by itself that could arguably be absorbed by the domain user table.

Comment: I'm just surprised at how little information/ how few examples are available on how to do this the "right" way. Even when new features and frameworks are in pre-release it typically doesn't stop the experts from pumping out blog posts illustrating how to leverage them. I think that's a good thing, even when they're bound to evolve.

Comment: My mistake on month!!

Comment: Try looking at IPrinciple, as it's in the BCL for .net and will allow you to us DI and IOC to test with. There are a number of articles around IPrinciple online. E.g. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that if you're going to inherit from IdentityUser, ASP.NET Identity related assemblies are coming along for the ride. You can't separate Identity from ASP.NET. The original examples in the question don't buy you much- in most cases you're probably better off just inheriting from `IdentityUser` if you're going to be using `IdentityUser` in your Domain project.

If your domain project truly needs to be free of ASP.NET related assemblies then you can leave the Identity related classes in your web project and create a separate `User` model in your Domain project an link the two programmatically, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974687/where-should-ef-migrations-go-my-class-library-project-or-my-asp-net-project/28975106#28975106).

Comment: Authentication is marginally a cross cutting concern, and as such you often have to play be different rules because of it.  While technically the authentication part is a presentation layer concern, you have to somehow connect this authentication with your domain authorization, and your presentation layer needs a way to store data for authentication.  So, short of implementing a new ASP.NET Identity provider to call an authentication service (rather than using the EF provider) you're going to have leakage.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [discussion on decoupling ASP.NET Identity here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/11/decoupling-aspnet-identify-from-your.html). And you can find examples on how it as implemented in the [open source project SimpleSecurity](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/).