# Where should EF Migrations go, my Class Library project or my ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

My solution contains:

- **FooBarAsp**, an asp project (provides a UI for the application)
- **FooBar**, a class library (the application)
- **FooBar.Tests**, a test project (tests the application)

FooBar uses EF 6 Code First, and contains a number of models, and a `DataContext`.  FooBarAsp uses Microsoft's Identity framework for user authentication, and has an `ApplicationDbContext`.  Both contexts play nice and work as expected.  Global.asax.cs should execute `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` (right?).  FooBar.Tests should execute `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` and won't care about migrations (right?).

**Should I EnableMigrations in FooBarAsp, or FooBar?  For both contexts?**

After running EnableMigrations in FooBar (just for kicks), my __MigrationHistory table contains two InitialCreate rows, one with ContextKey=FooBar.Models.DataContext and the other with ContextKey=FooBarAsp.Models.ApplicationDbContext.  So they're both being tracked already?  If so, (and since I did not enable automatic migrations), do I need to explicitly run *both* `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext>` and `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext>` in Global.asax.cs?

---

### Edit

**Why don't I want to move `ApplicationUser` into FooBar and merge `ApplicationDbContext` into `DataContext`?**

The stock `ApplicationUser` that comes with ASP is a separate entity (and separate `ApplicationDbContext`, which happens to point to the same database). ASP's `ApplicationUser` and the Identity framework take care of authentication, registration, email verification, login, logout, passwords, password strength, passwords resetting, two factor authentication, cookies, sessions, external login from sources like facebook/google, etc. FooBar doesn't know or care about any of that. FooBar's `User`s have a UserName, and ASP's `ApplicationUser`s have a UserName.  When a user logs in, I just look up Foobar's `User` by UserName, and that's who is logged in. So when I create a new `Blog` (where `Blog` is a FooBar entity), the author is FooBar's `User` (not `ApplicationUser`). The end result is that FooBar is not a Web/Desktop/Console/iPhone/Android application. It's a library that any of those things can reference, interact with, and provide a user interface for. The point is that FooBar is not polluted or biased by any of those user interfaces.

So I don't want to move `ApplicationUser` into FooBar because it's from the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity namespace, and FooBar doesn't know or care about ASP.NET (or WPF or whatever the interface happens to be).

Comment: I don't use code first, but, how about removing all data access out of the web project? Put that all in a separate class library?

Comment: Migrations are specific to your code first model, not your ASP.NET project therefore they should be in your FooBar library. Imagine you created another ASP.NET or WPF project and referenced FooBar. You would still want/need the migrations available.

Comment: @alexw Good point. I'm wondering if I even need migrations for the ASP usercontext..

Answer (score 7):

Like John said in his comment, you might be served well by moving all of your EF code into a separate class library. I typically create Web, Domain, DataAccess, and Test projects for a new solutions, and split them up even more down the road if it's necessary. This gives you some clear, basic separation of concerns up front. The Visual Studio Web project templates don't provide that, as it's designed to be self-contained in a single project.

Visual Studio's Web template is a good starting point for small projects but it pretty quickly becomes a mess as the project grows. Having the website (which is more or less your presentation layer), domain models & business logic, and data access all in the same project isn't particularly good practice. Partially separating them by leaving your user models and a separate `DbContext` behind in the web application can be even more confusing IMO, especially if your `ApplicationUser`s are going to participate in relationships with models from your domain class library.

I would suggest moving your `ApplicationUser` into the class library that contains your domain models, and take your `ApplicationDbContext` and move it into a DataAccess class library. You can take that one step further and combine your two DbContexts into one without much effort, unless you suspect that the project will grow large enough to require multiple `DbContexts. At that point, it becomes very apparent where your Migrations should live. Unless you're trying to abstract it away, your Initializer will always go in the application, which in your case is FooBarAsp, so you're correct that Global.asax is the place to set that up.

*However*, if this sounds unappealing to you and you'd like to keep your project structure as it currently is, it's my opinion that you would be best off configuring migrations for both `DbContext`s for consistency's sake. At that point, You'd have a set of Migrations in your web project (FooBarAsp) for the `ApplicationDbContext` that inherits from `IdentityDbContext` and another set of migrations that resided in your class library (FooBar). Both would need initializers in the Global.asax.cs of your web project.

**Edit based on OP's update:** I can see where you're coming from in your desire to keep ASP.NET related references out of your domain layer. It's basically impossible to keep this from happening without splitting up your user models in two as you've done. [This is something I asked about when VS2013 was still pre-RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011680/best-practices-for-integrating-asp-net-identity-do-they-exist) and never got a satisfactory answer because it's currently not possible to have an User model that works with Identity that doesn't pull in some ASP.NET related assemblies. However, in a somewhat analogous situation, the `DbGeography` type can be a very useful type to include in your domain layer, but it's impossible to use it without pulling in Entity Framework related assemblies. It really comes down to weighing the pros and cons and picking the lesser of two evils- be pragmatic in when and where you apply design patterns.

That said, if you do want to keep the `DbContext`s separate and the `ApplicationUser` in your web application, I'd suggest pulling out all the extraneous fields from the application user- in fact, just use the IdentityUser class itself instead of subclassing it since you'll be using it purely for authentication and authorization. However, I *believe* you'll still need to enable Migrations for both contexts and look into how to use [multiple contexts per database with EF6](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations), which wasn't possible in EF5.

Comment: See my Edit for a response to your first suggestion.  (`ApplicationUser`s do not participate in relationships with models from my domain class library.)

Comment: PS I really appreciate the thought you've put into your answer.