# Why do I have 2 Data context classes when creating a controller in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I added a database to my project, then I want to add a controller.

When the Add Controller window pops up, I am asked to choose Data context class.

Surprisingly, I found that there are 2 context classes:
One is called: my_database_name_dbEntities(projectname)

Another one is called:

ApplicationDbContext(projectname.Models) 
which is what I created when I added the Entity Framework object which connects to my database.

I am confused about

1. which one to use
2. what are the differences

Here is the screenshot 
[image]

---

**Update**

I tried both of them and here is what I have got:

1. If I choose the databasename_dbEntities, VS generates views and controller perfectly with no problems.
2. If I choose ApplicationDbContext, VS throws an error:

> Error
>
> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'lrc.Event'. One or more validation
>   errors were detected during model generation:
>
> AspNetUserLogin: : EntityType 'AspNetUserLogin' has no key defined.
>   Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> AspNetUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'AspNetUserLogins' is based on
>   type 'AspNetUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>
> '

[image]

**Update**

Now, I changed the super class from DbContext to IdentityDbContext for the projectname_dbEntities. 
So it looks like this now:

```
    public partial class projectname_dbEntities : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
        public projectname_dbEntities()
             : base("projectname_dbEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
            //: base("name=projectname_dbEntities")
        {
        }

        public static projectname_dbEntities Create()
        {
            return new projectname_dbEntities();
        }

.....
}
```

I wonder :

**what are the advantages of using the the derived class from IdentityDbContext over the DbContext?**

Comment: Use the one which corresponds to the tables you would like to access in the controller

Comment: hi @bit they both correspond to my tables..... that's why I am confused...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Identity DbContext confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902756/asp-net-identity-dbcontext-confusion)

Comment: This one should  clarify you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308959/set-asp-net-identity-connectionstring-property-in-net-4-5-1

Comment: hi @bit I can see from the questions you found for me that the suggestion is to use ApplicationDbContext as it inherits from Identity utility. But when I chose it, it throws an error which prevents me to do anything. Please see my update.

Comment: hi @bit I think my problem is different from the one you refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, when you create an ASP.NET MVC 5 project using the default template in Visual Studio 2013, you get a basic, ready-to-run website with the elementary Identity and Account management classes already in place.

There is a class `ApplicationDbContext`. This is the Entity Framework context used to manage interaction between your application and the database where your Account data is persisted (which may, or may not be the same database that will be used by the rest of our application) and this class inherits from `IdentityDbContext`.

`IdentityDbContext` is basically a regular `DbContext` with two `DbSets`. One for the `Users` and one for the `Roles`.

If you don't want use `ASP.NET Identity`, you can ignore it or mix it into your own `DbContext` class.

Comment: It clears me alot! So do you mean that I should use the projectname_dbEntities context class?

Comment: thanks. but if I use the projectname_dbEntities context class, then I will not have the access to the Identity facility class to use which is the latest built-in helper class. so I am confused why do they(MS) add this class if no one uses it?

Comment: You can keep both or mix them. if you want use `projectname_dbEntities`, this class should inherits from `IdentityDbContext` and add available `Dbsets` in `ApplicationDbContext` into `projectname_dbEntities`.

Comment: Thanks a lot~! Where can I find the method to mix them?